# jQuery Mobile: How To Put Listview Popup on Top of Page Content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-popup

I'm creating a simple UI for mobile app using jQuery mobile. [This is my code (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/BTjct/1/).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- start -->
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">

             <h1>Infographic</h1>

        </div>
        <!-- end data role header -->
        <div data-role="content" role="main" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
            <div class="infografik-image">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/440x699" />
            </div>
            <!-- end infografik-image -->
        </div>
        <!-- end content -->
        <!-- start footer -->
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" style="display:none;" id="pop">
            <li><a href="faq.html" rel="external">FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="aduan.html" rel="external">Report</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="infographic.html" rel="external">Infographic</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" rel="external" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="news.html" rel="external">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html" rel="external">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:toggle();" rel="external" id="displayText">More</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /navbar -->
        </div>
        <!-- /footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- end page -->
</div>
<!-- end container -->
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#pop {
    display:none;
}
.infografik-image {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.infografik-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto!important;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

JS:

```
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("pop");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if (ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "More";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        ele.style.width = "50%";
        ele.style.float = "right";
        ele.style.marginRight = "3%";
        ele.style.paddingTop = "25px";
        ele.style.paddingBottom = "25px";
        text.innerHTML = "Close";
    }
}
```

I created a small popup. When user tap on the 'More' tab, my popup will be shown. I create this using javascript (i'm JS & jQuery noob).

What I actually want this popup do is, display it on top of the page content. In this case, I want it to be shown on the top of the infographic image.

If you have another suggestion/resources/tutorial that easy to follow, please share it to me. I want to learn it.

[image]

Comment: Why not use the popup widget: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/

Comment: check this one http://jsfiddle.net/BTjct/3/ and tell if any corrections.

Comment: @Aravinth looks ok. But how to make it float at the bottom like this (http://i.imgur.com/I1D03Iq.jpg)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the jQuery Mobile Popup widget:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnToggle", function(){

    $(this).find(".ui-btn-text").text("Close");
    var bottomPos = $(document).height() - $.mobile.getScreenHeight() + 62 - $(document).scrollTop();  

    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("#popupMenu")
        .popup( "open", {})
        .on( "popupafterclose", function( event, ui ) {
            $("#btnToggle .ui-btn-text").text("More");
            $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
        })
        .parents(".ui-popup-container")
        .css({
            "right": "4px",
            "left" : "auto",
            "bottom": bottomPos + "px",
            "top": "auto"
        });

});
```

The code first changes the button text to Close by finding the appropriate SPAN inside the button with the class ui-btn-text.
- It then calculates where the popup should go, taking into account the scroll position of the body.
- Next, turn off scrolling on the body while the popup is active
- the rest resets the text and scroll on popup close and positions the popup just above the button.

> Here is the updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BTjct/8/)**

Comment: Thanks @ezanker. I test it on my android phone and it looks ok. But when I test it on my iphone, I get like this: http://i.imgur.com/otvj0ZO.jpg

This is my code structure: http://jsfiddle.net/t8h7X/

Anything wrong with my code? Or, the JS couldn't work well on iPhone?

Comment: I visited your fiddle on my iPhone and I do not see the problem. The popup opens at the bottom as expected...

Comment: maybe my previous code is mess up with my custom CSS. Ok, now I create a new clean HTML file & use pure jQuery CSS. This is my screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/oSODCMO.jpg

Do you get it same like mine? Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: no, when I visit your fiddle, I get the expected results. iPhone 4s iOS 7.1.

Comment: Do you have the vieport meta tag in your htm head: <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width' />

Answer (score 1):

Change your java script code like below.

```
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("pop");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if (ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "More";
} else {
     ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "Close";

    $("#pop").css({top: 50,left:280, position:'absolute'});
}
}
```

Refer this <kbd>[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BTjct/3/)</kbd>

Comment: looks ok. But how to make it float at the bottom like this (http://i.imgur.com/I1D03Iq.jpg)?

Comment: if you want the pop like in the image, you need to find the height of the image(that is your placehold image) and set according to that.